# Replacing derivative of a function

Tags: replacement

I want to replace the time derivative (only time derivative part) of a function with another function. If the term has also a derivative with x (space), how can I do it? 
I tried the following but that results in Binomial function:

If I have:

```
{Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t] -> (\[Lambda]*(3*u[x, t]^2*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]^2 + u[x, t]^3*Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t]))/3}
```

All what I want is to take the nx- derivative of the right hand side of the rule, I tried the following but it resulted in Binomial function:

```
   repRule={Derivative[nx_, 1][u][x, t] -> D[(\[Lambda]*(3*u[x, t]^2*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]^2 + u[x, t]^3*Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t]))/3, {x, nx}]}
```

And when I apply it to a simple expression like:

```
ss=\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
 RowBox[{"(", 
 RowBox[{"1", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
 Derivative],
 MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t]
```

I get from ss/.repRule:

```
     (\[Lambda]*(3*Inactive[Sum][Binomial[1, K[1]]*D[Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]^2, {x, 1 -       K[1]}]*Inactive[Sum][u[x, t]*Derivative[K[1], 0][u][x, t], {K[1], 0, K[1]}], 
 {K[1], 0, 1}] + Inactive[Sum][Binomial[1, K[1]]*D[Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t], {x, 1 - K[1]}]*
 Inactive[Sum][D[u[x, t], {x, -K[2]}]*Multinomial[K[1], -K[2], K[2]]*Derivative[K[1], 0][u][x, t]*Derivative[K[2], 0][u][x, t], {K[1], 0, K[1]}, {K[2], 0, K[1]}], 
{K[1], 0, 1}]))/3
```

Your help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use [`RuleDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) in the definition of `repRule`

```
repRule = {(Derivative[nx_, 1][u][x, t]) :> 
    D[(λ*(3*u[x, t]^2*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]^2 + 
          u[x, t]^3*Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t]))/3, {x, nx}]};

ss = Derivative[1, 1][u][x, t];

ss /. repRule

(* (1/3)*λ*(6*u[x, t]*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]^3 + 
      9*u[x, t]^2*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]*
        Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t] + u[x, t]^3*
        Derivative[3, 0][u][x, t]) *)
```

Comment: @Bob.Hanon Thanks, it works.